# Export rows with foreign keys to another database

Tags: mysql, symfony, foreign-keys, export

I'm working with msyql and symfony2. I have a database with 15 tables. I want to export all data starting from a row in the main table, go to each table I have and select all data related to that and move it to another database (which is not empty) and also not loose foreign key relations.

I will try to explain it with a very basic example.
 [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTVjh.png)

So I want to select the user with id 1 and from that to select all threads connected to that user and from those threads I want to select all their posts connected to them. All this data I want to export it to another database (this is not empty also) and keep the data integrity with all its relations.

Is there a tool or how can I create an export script like this?

Comment: I created a script to do something similar (as I did not find any tool or prepared script). What I did was creating a list of to be copied classes, loaded them, cloned them, followed their association attributes, cloned them as well with reference to the associated clone and so forth. In my case I needed to copy it into the same database but you could create some import script for another database as well.